# How to clear DataTable.HasErrors?

Tags: c#, ultrawingrid

There is a datatable with 2 columns, upon submission there is a validation checking using `dataTable.HasErrors` and blocked the form submission.

Now based on certain logic, the column with error will be set invisible by setting `Hidden = true` and proceed with form submission, obviously it failed to proceed as `dataTable.HasErrors` still is true.

So when I set `Hidden = true` to the particular column, I also set `SupportDataErrorInfo = false`. On the form I can tell that the error icon has gone but `dataTable.HasErrors` remain true?

Comment: If you are talking about the System.Data.DataTable.HasErrors property then on MSDN docs you can read _After reconciling each error, clear the errors with the ClearErrors method of the DataRow._

Comment: @Steve Can `ClearErrors` targeting only particular column?

Comment: The problem as I can understand is that also if you set the column hidden, you still are trying to submit the column data. You should fix the error or not submit at all the column. I can't say more that this because I have no idea about your logic and database rules.

Comment: Some states can not be set directly but only via other states, I think.

Comment: Both columns are just simple null validation and DB accepting null value, so even though the column is hidden and submitted, its fine. Problem now is after hide the error remain

Comment: @TaW Do you mind to elaborate more to shed me some light?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. While true for the Row states, there simply seems to be no way to clear the DataTable.HasErrors property. Short of correcting the errors or (maybe worth considering) removing the data that have the errors..

Comment: `DataTable` has no `Hidden` property. Did you mean some `DataGrid`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Yes Alex